# Using images with 5 or more channel in a tf.data pipeline

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow, python-3.x

I have a data generator used to train FCNs (eg Unets) that uses tf.data.  The image parser followed by the creation of the tf.data dataset for the training images looks like:

```
    
def parse_image(img_path: str) -> dict:
    """Load an image and its annotation (mask) and returning
    a dictionary.

    Parameters
    ----------
    img_path : str
        Image (not the mask) location.

    Returns
    -------
    dict
        Dictionary mapping an image and its annotation.
    """
    #print(img_path)
    image = tf.io.read_file(img_path)
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image, channels=3)
    #image = tfio.experimental.image.decode_tiff(image)
    image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, tf.uint8)


    mask_path = tf.strings.regex_replace(img_path, "images", "annotations")
    mask_path = tf.strings.regex_replace(mask_path, "jpg", "png")
    mask = tf.io.read_file(mask_path)

    mask = tf.image.decode_png(mask, channels=1)
    mask = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(mask, tf.uint8)
    mask=tf.squeeze(tf.one_hot(mask, depth=n_class))
    image.set_shape([img_size[0],img_size[0],3])
    mask.set_shape([img_size[0],img_size[0],n_class])
    #mask is one hot in more than 3 classes, use gdal
    #mask=tf.py_function(onehotpreprocess, [mask_path], tf.uint8)


    return {'image': image, 'segmentation_mask': mask}

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(TrainFolder + "*.jpg", seed=42)
train_dataset = train_dataset.map(parse_image)
```

That works fine for 3 channel images (or 1 channel).  But now I want to use it for images with 5 (or more) channels stored as tif files.  tf.io.experiemntal() does not work.  When I work with such images, I usually use gdal_array.LoadFile() to load them and that works fine.  But when I try to use this in the data parser.  It won't work.  I understand why: the file paths are in a tf format and gdal_array.LoadFile() expects an ordinary Python string. But I can't seem to figure how or where I can convert the file path in tf format.

Any ideas?

Comment: From the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/decode_jpeg) `tf.io.decode_jpeg` can handle only, 0, 1, or 3 channels images. What if you save your images as (compresed) numpy arrays?

Comment: Barring compression issues (gdal is a very potent copressor of images), I guess that might work.  I found the tutorial on loading numpy arrays.  But it does mean a re-write of the parser above because my masks are in png but in the same folder.  So this is a fallback, but I'd still prefer a solution where I can comvert those tf paths into strings for reading by gdal_array. But thanks!

Comment: Sure, the issue with paths is that are represented as string tensors. Maybe you can write a custom `tf.keras.Sequence` and then wrap it in a `tf.data.Dataset`